# The curve $x^5=y^3$ is manifold of class $C^1$ but not class $C^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I know that if a function $f:\mathbb R \to\mathbb R$ is $C^\infty$ then the graph is smooth submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$ however. If our function $y=f(x)=x^{5/3}$ is $C^1$ how can I conclude that the submanifold $\Gamma_{(x,f(x))|x\in \mathbb R}$ is of class $C^1$ but not $C^2$, I am having hard time to conclude with logical explanations.(intuitively i feel but explicitly i fail)

Comment: Edit your post to include your efforts. Perhaps you should argue that if $X\subset\Bbb R^2$ is a $C^k$ submanifold, then *either* projection onto the $x$-axis or projection onto the $y$-axis must be a $C^k$ chart.